# resizing markers based on zooming in Googlemap V2 android

Tags: android, google-maps

I put some markers on map. the size is just right on zoom level 19 (I made bitmaps with real sizes and passed them in to markers). How To re-size markers on google map v2 when user zooms in or out in map?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need click and info window for those, I suggest using [GroundOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay) instead.